# NewsArticle not validing: "The attribute image.width has an invalid value."

Tags: images, schema.org, google-rich-snippets-tool, json-ld

I'm using Google's template to mark up my blog and it seems that if I were to change the value of the `width`/`height`, it instantly tells me:

> The attribute image.width has an invalid value.

The following is a template that Google has provided:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "NewsArticle",
  "mainEntityOfPage": {
    "@type": "WebPage",
    "@id": "https://google.com/article"
  },
  "headline": "Article headline",
  "image": {
    "@type": "ImageObject",
    "url": "https://google.com/thumbnail1.jpg",
    "height": 800,
    "width": 800
  },
  "datePublished": "2015-02-05T08:00:00+08:00",
  "dateModified": "2015-02-05T09:20:00+08:00",
  "author": {
    "@type": "Person",
    "name": "John Doe"
  },
   "publisher": {
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "Google",
    "logo": {
      "@type": "ImageObject",
      "url": "https://google.com/logo.jpg",
      "width": 600,
      "height": 60
    }
  },
  "description": "A most wonderful article"
}
</script>
```

The following source code is what I have changed:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "NewsArticle",
  "mainEntityOfPage": {
    "@type": "WebPage",
    "@id": "https://google.com/article"
  },
  "headline": "Article headline",
  "image": {
    "@type": "ImageObject",
    "url": "https://google.com/thumbnail1.jpg",
    "height": 800,
    "width": **600**
  },
  "datePublished": "2015-02-05T08:00:00+08:00",
  "dateModified": "2015-02-05T09:20:00+08:00",
  "author": {
    "@type": "Person",
    "name": "John Doe"
  },
   "publisher": {
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "Google",
    "logo": {
      "@type": "ImageObject",
      "url": "https://google.com/logo.jpg",
      "width": 600,
      "height": 60
    }
  },
  "description": "A most wonderful article"
}
</script>
```

Is is a bug from Google? Or am I just really lost?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See Google documentation: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/articles

> Images should be at least 696 pixels wide.

So this one works for me:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "NewsArticle",
  "mainEntityOfPage": {
    "@type": "WebPage",
    "@id": "https://google.com/article"
  },
  "headline": "Article headline",
  "image": {
    "@type": "ImageObject",
    "url": "https://google.com/thumbnail1.jpg",
    "width": 696,
    "height": 100
  },
  "datePublished": "2015-02-05T08:00:00+08:00",
  "dateModified": "2015-02-05T09:20:00+08:00",
  "author": {
    "@type": "Person",
    "name": "John Doe"
  },
   "publisher": {
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "Google",
    "logo": {
      "@type": "ImageObject",
      "url": "https://google.com/logo.jpg",
      "width": 10,
      "height": 60
    }
  },
  "description": "A most wonderful article"
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Google is looking for a specific size.  Their [Article objects](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/article#article_types) `publisher.logo` points to their [AMP logo guidelines](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/article#logo-guidelines) which says:

> - The file must be a raster file, such as .jpg, .png, or .gif. Don't use vector files, such as .svg or .eps.
> - Don't use animation.
> - The graphic part of the logo should be legible on the background color.
> - The **logo must be a rectangle, not a square**.
> - The **logo should fit in a 60x600px rectangle, and either be exactly 60px high (preferred), or exactly 600px wide. For example,
>     450x45px would not be acceptable, even though it fits within the
>     600x60px rectangle**.